# Redirect Everything from Certain Domain UrlRewriting in Apache2 with multiple Domains and Wildcards

Tags: apache, apache2, conditional-statements, url-rewriting

A wuestion about Conditional Urlrewriding:
Currently this works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.com$
RewriteRule ^$ somepage.htm [R=301,L]
```

What it does is, it redirects the "root" of all these three sites via 301 permanent to somepage.htm

As site1.com and site2.com are aliases of eachother `site2.com/someotherpage` or `site3.com/folder1/someotherpage` all work. However, I would like to remporarily redirect ALL and Everything from the second site to the somepage.htm sothat any other page does not show up under site2.com. How to set a wildcard at the end of site2.com to catch everything?

How to change the RewriteCond? 
Thanks very much for suggestion/answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not attached to using just one rule, this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com$
RewriteRule ^$ somepage.htm [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^somepage.htm
RewriteRule .* somepage.htm [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps.